# CSS styling table tds

Tags: html, css, html-table

There are lots of pages I need to work with , the good thing is they all have the same structure. And finally I want to achieve a visual effect like this.

```
<tr><td style="width:15%;">label text</td>
    <td style="width:35%;"><input type='text' style="width:50%"; /></td>
    <td style="width:15%;">label text</td>
    <td style="width:35%;"><input type='text' style="width:50%"; /></td>
</tr>
```

How can I applying CSS to a plain table and renders the same visual result like this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't without either using CSS3 or helping the CSS out by applying some classes:

```
<tr>
  <td class="label"><label for="input1">label text</label></td>
  <td class="field"><input type="text" id="input1"></td>
  <td class="label"><label for="input2">label text</label></td>
  <td class="field"><input type="text" id="input2"></td>
</tr>
```

with:

```
td.label { width: 15%; }
td.field { width: 35%; }
td.field input { width: 35%; }
```

Either that or using Javascript.